# Intuition behind $m(b-a) \leq L(P,f) \leq U(P,f) \leq M(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

In the text "An Introduction to Measure and Integration by Rana" I'm having trouble gaining intuition behind the following Proposition in $(1)$

$(1)$

$$\text{Proposition}$$

$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,  \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \, \, \, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,$For every partition $P$ of $[a,b]$:

$$m(b-a) \leq L(P,f) \leq U(P,f) \leq M(b-a)$$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$where $m:=\inf\{f(x)|a\le x\le b\} \, \text{and} \, M:=\sup\{f(x)|a\le x\le b\}$

$\text{Remark}$

$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$Substituting one can observe the following:

$$\inf\big\{f(x)| a \leq x\leq b \big\}(b-a) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf \big\{f(x)|x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i} \big\}(x_{i}-x_{i-1}) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sup \big\{f(x)|x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i} \big\}(x_{i}-x_{i-1}) \leq \sup\big\{f(x)| a \leq x\leq b \big\}$$

$\text{Remark}$

Looking at the proportion I managed to break $(1)$ in to various cases:

Case $(1)$:
$$\inf\big\{f(x)| a \leq x\leq b \big\}(b-a) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf \big\{f(x)|x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i} \big\}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$

Case $(2)$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf \big\{f(x)|x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i} \big\}(x_{i}-x_{i-1}) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sup \big\{f(x)|x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i} \big\}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$

Case $(3)$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sup \big\{f(x)|x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i} \big\}(x_{i}-x_{i-1}) \leq \sup\big\{f(x)| a \leq x\leq b \big\}(b-a)$$

For each of the distinct cases I'm having trouble putting things together and creating a picture?

Comment: The point is that $L(P,f)$ is non decreasing, and the finer the partition $P$ the better is the approximation of the area by $L(P,f)$. On the other hand $b-a$ comes from the coarsest partition of $I$, namely $z_0=a,z_1=b.$ Similarly for $U(P,f)$.

Comment: I think you should draw a picture.

Comment: @user 1987 what do you mean by the "coarsest partition" ?

Comment: @Zophikel Coarsest means the smallest number of subintervals. And the smallest number is obviously 1.

Comment: so @user1987 $U(P,f)$ is non-decreasing and the finer the paramation the better we can approximate our upper sum ?

Comment: @Zophikel $U(P,f)$ is non-increasing. Also, the ultimate goal is not to approximate upper/lower sum. The goal is to make the gap $U(P,f)-L(P,f)$ smaller and smaller so that whats in between, namely, the definite integral, gets squeezed in.

Comment: @user1987 then how would it be visualzed ?, that's what i'm having trouble doing I thought breaking it into cases would be helpful, but as it turns out :>( it didn't pan out.

Comment: So the definite integral is bounded between $\inf \big\{ f(x) | a \leq x \leq b \big\}$ and $\sup \big\{ f(x) | a \leq x \leq b \big\}$

Comment: @Zophikel Do you agree that $m(b-a)$ is a lower sum? Do you agree that any other partition of $[a,b]$ is finer than the partition $z_0=a,z_1=b$? Then the first inequality follows by the fact that $L(P,f)$ is non-decreasing. Basically, $m(b-a)$ is the area of the smallest rectangle that you can fit inside the area below the graph of $f$ and above $[a,b]$.

Comment: i'm beginning to get it but I need a  picture to fully understand i'm sorry :>(.

Comment: @user1987 $m(b-a)$ would not be the lower sum, so the intuition behind case $(1):$                                                                                                      $$\inf\big\{f(x)| a \leq x\leq b \big\}(b-a) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf \big\{f(x)|x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i} \big\}(x_{i}-x_{i}-1)$$ Is basically  the area of the smallest rectangle that fits inside $f$ above $[a,b]$ is less then or equal to  $L(P,f)$ note( which approximates $f$ from the inside on the   interval $x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i}$).

Comment: @user1987 carrying onto the second case, recall: $ L(P,f) \leq U(P,f) $, as per full observed: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf \big\{f(x)|x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i} \big\}(x_{i}-x_{i}-1) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sup \big\{f(x)|x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i} \big\}(x_{i}-x_{i}-1)$$ Essentially says that: The lower sum is less then or greater then  upper sum on the respective partition.

Comment: @user1987 in the first comment I should have said on the respective pariation

Comment: @user1987 the final case intuition is similar to case $(1)$

Comment: $M(b-a)$ is the rectangle bounding anything inside it. $L \leq U$ stems from definition.

Comment: Well yeah @Nameless is should be obvious that: $L \leq U$, what i'm trying to do is to establish the key point of the $\text{Propostion}$ which looks like the gap between the upper and lower sums is getting smaller which would approximate our function $f(x)$

Comment: For the sake of getting intuition, it would be much more useful to draw a picture than doing verbal discussion. Also, examples are much more useful than abstract manipulation of symbols.

Comment: Actuall I did find a picture that only corresponds to two cases: https://mathequality.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/left-right-midpoints.png

Comment: My edit was for typos only: x_{i}-1 should have been x_{i-1}. .... BTW when the subscript or suoerscript is a single keyboard character you don't need to use brace brackets : x_i is the same as x_{i}. This applies to function-symbols  & some other notation too : e.g. \sin x and \sqrt x and \overline x   .   & There are other faster ways to make a central display than \;\;\;\;  but I hardly ever used them so I've forgotten how.........& the symbol \quad gives a much wider blank space than \;

Comment: The statement in the title is so obvious that no extra intuition is called for. Any "formal proof" makes it less believable $\ldots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L(P, f) = \sum{m_i\Delta x_i}$ and $U(P, f) = \sum{M_i\Delta x_i}$

Case $(1)$:

$m(b-a) = \sum{m\Delta x_i} \le \sum{m_i\Delta x_i}$, because $m$ is minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$, and each $m_i$ is a local minimum for each $\Delta x_i$, so $m_i \ge m$ $\forall i$

Case $(2)$:

$\sum{m_i\Delta x_i} \le \sum{M_i\Delta x_i}$, because $m_i$ and $M_i$ are local $min$ and $max$ for each $\Delta x_i$, so $m_i \le M_i$

Case $(3)$:

$\sum{M_i\Delta x_i} \le \sum{M \Delta x_i} = M(b-a)$, because $M$ is maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$, and each $M_i$ is a local maximum for each $\Delta x_i$, so $M_i \le M$ $\forall i$

Comment: Can you include a visual in your answer please

Comment: @Zophikel what do you mean by visual?

Comment: A picture basically

Comment: Is my intution correct:the goal is to make the gap U(P,f)−L(P,f) smaller and smaller so that whats in between, namely, the definite integral, gets squeezed in.

Comment: @Zophikel Maybe this will help? https://imgur.com/a/Lvkge

Comment: ahh so the gap between the upper and lower sum is getting smaller and smaller correct ?

Comment: @Zophikel, Yes, the goal is to split $[a, b]$ into smaller and smaller intervals, and if $\lim_{n\to \infty}(U(P_n, f) - L(P_n, f)) = 0$, then integral exists and equal to $\lim_{n\to \infty}(U(P_n, f))$

Comment: So what would the process of proving a function is Riemann Integrable on $f$ look like if I may ask :>).

Comment: One way would is to prove that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(P, f) - L(P, f) < \varepsilon$

Comment: So $\varepsilon$ would be our partition, you have a link to a practical example ?

Comment: $\varepsilon > 0$ is a constant and then $P_{\varepsilon}$ is a partition that corresponds to it, such that $U(P_{\varepsilon}, f) - L(P_{\varepsilon}, f) < \varepsilon$. The intuition here is that we can always make $U(P, f)$ and $L(U, f)$ as close together as we want by finding appropriate partition

Comment: ahhh ok i'll have too look at practical examples in my textbook

Answer (score 1):

I try to think of it less rigorously. The maximum possible sum, is the maximum value of the function times the length of the interval. Or, if you think visually, the box with the biggest area on the interval is that where the height is the biggest possible (i.e the max/sup). A similar analogy can be used for the inf.